# Multiple if/else in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to increment a variable in a `map()` in jsx and hide elements bases on it. I get the following error

> Failed to compile.
>   Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...?

I think this is the row that is messing with me
`{myIncrement % 2 == 0 && <div data-key-id={row.key} key={row.key} className="">}`

Any ideas? (I'm not a React dev full time so a bit lost in jsx)

Here is the full code for that part

```
{props.config.map(row => (
  (row.isRequired || props.data[row.key]) && 
     <React.Fragment>
        {row.isFullWidth ? 
          <div data-key-id={row.key} key={row.key} className="">
            <div className="">
              <div className="">some key</div>
                <div className="">some value</div>
            </div>
          </div>
         :
          <React.Fragment>
            {myIncrement % 2 == 0 && <div data-key-id={row.key} key={row.key} className="">}
              <div className="">
                <div className="">{row.key}:</div>
                <div className="">{row.value}</div>
              </div>
            {myIncrement % 2 == 0 && </div>}

            {myIncrement = !row.isFullWidth ? myIncrement + 1 : myIncrement}
          </React.Fragment>
         }
      </React.Fragment>
))}
```

Comment: Can you add the surrounding code? The error you are receiving suggests you are returning multiple JSX elements in your component, which isn't allowed, they should be wrapped with a single component

Comment: `            {myIncrement % 2 == 0 && <div data-key-id={row.key} key={row.key} className="">}
              <div className="">
                <div className="">{row.key}:</div>
                <div className="">{row.value}</div>
              </div>
            {myIncrement % 2 == 0 && </div>}`
You can not separeta opening and enclosing tags. They must be returned together

Comment: @dbramwell The error is isolated to this code and it's is the `myIncrement % 2 === 0` code does cause the error, I just don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

## First problem: missing fragments around map

Basically you can't have a jsx that looks like

```
<foo/>
<bar/>
```

because React can't know the root element and it needs that do do the React magic that transforms JSX into reactive HTML, instead you need to have

```
<>
  <foo/>
  <bar/>
</>
```

<sub>`<>` is a shorthand for `<React.Fragment>`</sub>

That is what the error message about adjacent elements means. Your map will create adjacent elements:

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].map(letter => <div>{letter}</div>)

will produce

<div>a</div>
<div>b</div>
<div>c</div>
```

To fix this error, simply add a fragment around your map:

```
<>
  { props.config.map(row => (
    /* ... */
  )}
</>
```

## Second problem: invalid JSX syntax

This is invalid JSX:

```
{ myIncrement % 2 == 0 && <div data-key-id={row.key} key={row.key} className=""> }
  <div className="">
    <div className="">{row.key}:</div>
    <div className="">{row.value}</div>
  </div>
{myIncrement % 2 == 0 && </div>}
```

I know it *makes sense* while writing it, but it won't compile, because React will try to evaluate `myIncrement % 2 == 0 && <div data-key-id={row.key} key={row.key} className="">` and `myIncrement % 2 == 0 && </div>` separately and it is not possible (yet?).

You can obtain something similar as follow:

```
// define this part of the component somewhere
const Foo = ({ key, value}) => (
  <div>
    <div>{key}:</div>
    <div>{value}</div>
  </div>
);

// surround it or not by a div, depending on the increment value
{ myIncrement % 2 == 0 ? (
    <div data-key-id={row.key} key={row.key}>
      <Foo key={row.key} value={row.value}/>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <Foo key={row.key} value={row.value}/>
  )
}
```

Comment: No, the problem is happening inside the second `React.Fragment`

Comment: DONT need a fragment between map, because it returns an array, and array can be rendered in JSX. That part was just fine.

Comment: This is not the right answer either. I still need the second content to be inside the wrapper. But I see the problem with my first statement, but thats how i kinda have to do for it to work. I think I'm gone have to resolve it outside JSX and string concat myself.

Answer (score 0):

What you can not do:

```
  <React.Fragment>
    {myIncrement % 2 == 0 && <div data-key-id={row.key} key={row.key} className="">} // <= opening tag
      <div className="">
        <div className="">{row.key}:</div>
        <div className="">{row.value}</div>
      </div>
    {myIncrement % 2 == 0 && </div>} // <= Enclosing tag

    {myIncrement = !row.isFullWidth ? myIncrement + 1 : myIncrement}
  </React.Fragment>
```

Its diallowed, because You trying to render a `<div>` opening tag, and than in other statement the `</div>` tag.
They must belongs together like:

```
  <React.Fragment>
    {myIncrement % 2 == 0 ? (
      <div data-key-id={row.key} key={row.key} className="">
        <div className=""> // <= could be a new component 
          <div className="">{row.key}:</div>
          <div className="">{row.value}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
    : (
      <div className=""> // <= could be a new component
        <div className="">{row.key}:</div>
        <div className="">{row.value}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }

    {myIncrement = !row.isFullWidth ? myIncrement + 1 : myIncrement}
  </React.Fragment>
```

Comment: The only problem I see in this answer is that you are not providing the "else" case. I think he wants to wrap those divs inside that outer one if the confition is fullfiled but display the inner content without the wrapper if not.

Comment: Sure, he is talking about hiding elements if the condition is not fullfiled but i think that he is trying to hide the wrapper, not the content. Either way, he won't be committing that mistake cause we can see that he knows how to display (or not) an element.

Comment: Yea I'm not trying to hide the content, only the wrapper if statement is fulfulled.

Comment: I see. Updated.

Comment: This is still not gone work. I need the content to be inside the wrapper. So basically two "elements" inside a wrapper.

Comment: Have you tryed?

Comment: I can see that it wont work as expected. This will render like index=1, with wrapper, index=2, without wrapper, index=3, with wrapper, index=4 without wrapper... I need it to be open wrapper > content > content > close wrapper

Comment: Ahh I see. than you must restructure your code. It s not possible in this way.

Comment: maybe create a sub arrays, and render them together like const a = [[1, 2], [2, 4]];

Comment: By the way, your code above would also not wrap "two "elements" inside a wrapper". For that the {myIncrement % 2 == 0 && </div>} should be Odd number like this: {myIncrement % 2 == 1 && </div>}

Comment: Yes I had changed that in my code before the copy. Thanks for the heads up anyway.

Comment: In that case, would be great if you would respect my time with a thumbs up.